# Pyspark apply different reduce function based key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Say I have some data that looks like this

```
data =[('yes_sum', np.array([2, 2, 2])),
 ('yes_sum', np.array([3, 3, 3])),
 ('no_sum', np.array([4, 4, 4])),
 ('no_sum', np.array([6, 6, 6]))]
```

which I convert to a rdd.

```
rdd_data = sc.parallelize(data)
```

I want to to sum the arrays with the key `'yes_sum'` but merge the arrays with key `'no_sum'` together. So it looks like this:

```
[('yes_sum', array([5, 5, 5])), ('no_sum', array([4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6]))]
```

I only know how to sum the arrays by key using:

```
rdd_data.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y).collect()
```

which I get:

```
[('yes_sum', array([5, 5, 5])), ('no_sum', array([10, 10, 10]))]
```

but that's not what I'm looking for. I was thinking something like this:

```
rdd_data.reduceByKey(
    lambda x,y: if x.key() == 'yes_sum' x+y else np.concatenate((x, y))
).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your syntax:

```
lambda x,y: if x.key() == 'yes_sum' x+y else np.concatenate((x, y))
```

is incorrect. Instead you could have written:

```
lambda x,y: x+y if x.key() == 'yes_sum' else np.concatenate((x, y))
```

but this will result in:

> `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'key'`

When you are doing a `reduceByKey`, the `key` part is unknown to the reduce function itself. Spark has already done the job of grouping data from like keys together, and passing it to the appropriate reducers.

In order to accomplish what you're looking to do, you need to `filter` the `rdd` before calling `reduceByKey`. Then you can apply a different `reduce` function based on the filtering, and union your results.

For example:

```
yes_rdd = rdd_data.filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'yes_sum')\
    .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y)

no_rdd = rdd_data.filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'yes_sum')\
    .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: np.concatenate((x, y)))

print(yes_rdd.union(no_rdd).collect())
#[('yes_sum', array([5, 5, 5])), ('no_sum', array([4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6]))]
```